# It is possible to numpy calculate below without loop?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have 10x10x4 array, and let say its dimension is a, b, c.

For each element c with respect to (a, b) ,
How can I calculate the multiplication of c.T × c ?

c: 1×4 matrix

c.T × c: 4×4 matrix

So the result has the array in the form of 10×10×(4×4) shape.

Is it possible without for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use `np.einsum` for that:

```
np.einsum('...i,...j->...ij', arr, arr, optimize = True)
```

You can also use brodcasted multiplication in this case:

```
arr[:,:, None, :] * arr[:,:,:, None]
```

Comment: 1) I haven't been 'sir' since I left the military.  You can use `@` to address folks here 2) if you want to inline code use the backwards slanting single quotes 3) `np.einsum` is pretty much the best thing about `numpy` if you do high-dimensional math, espeically since they implemented the `optimize` parameter

Comment: Thank you sir, I'm reading about 'einsum.'

By the way, I couldn't understand ellipsis parts. Because when I compare the results of some examples in numpy Note, np.einsum('ii', a) and np.einsum('i...i', a), it is same.

Also, may I ask you one question more?

For A matrix(10x10)  and B matrix(4x1) matrix, I have to reconstruct
these two matrices to 10x10x4 matrix.
So what I mean by is for each matrix A, multiplying with B.

Comment: You want to look into [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) as well if you don't know how to do things like that.